# GUI component for folder choosing with select option

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I need to create a component as shown in the figure - a tree with directory selection via checkbox.  Is there is a built in component for this (like others such as `JFileChooser` etc.)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there is a built in component for this (like others such as `JFileChooser` etc.)?

No, not a ready-made component for that specific purpose.  OTOH it is not very difficult to throw something together using a `JTree`.

You might start with the code shown on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui.  It uses a tree.

[image]

### Nodes with check-boxes

> ..a tree with directory selection via checkbox.

The selection via. checkbox makes it a bit more tricky.  Here are two possible approaches.

#### Use a renderer

This allows multi-selection in the same way that multiple nodes might be selected in a standard tree, but swaps the BG selection color for a checked check-box.

It then becomes very easy to use the inbuilt methods such as [`JTree.getSelectionPaths()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getSelectionPaths%28%29) and handles multi/single selection with a single method call.

[image: Check-box tree]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.io.*;

class TreeWithCheck {

    public static Component getTree(int selectionMode) {
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(selectionMode);
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        SelectableTreeCellRenderer renderer =
            new SelectableTreeCellRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
        Dimension d = scroll.getPreferredSize();
        scroll.setPreferredSize(
            new Dimension((int)d.getWidth()*2, (int)d.getHeight()));

        return scroll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel trees = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,5,5));

                trees.add(
                    getTree(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION));
                trees.add(
                    getTree(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, trees);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SelectableTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox selected;
    private JPanel renderComponent;

    public SelectableTreeCellRenderer() {
        selected = new JCheckBox();
        renderComponent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        renderComponent.add(selected,BorderLayout.WEST);

        selected.setOpaque(false);
        renderComponent.setOpaque(false);
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
        JTree tree,
        Object value,
        boolean sel,
        boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf,
        int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {

        Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            tree,
            value,
            false, // we pass 'false' rather than 'sel'
            expanded,
            leaf,
            row,
            hasFocus);

        selected.setSelected(sel);
        renderComponent.add(c,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return renderComponent;
    }
}
```

#### Define a custom object

One way you might approach it is to put custom objects into the tree, rather than `File` instances.  The custom object might be called a `SelectableDirectory` and have a `File directory` & `boolean selected` as the attributes.  Something like:

```
public class SelectableDirectory {

    private File directory;
    private boolean selected;
    // getters and setters, constructor..
}
```

Use a custom renderer for the tree that returns a `JPanel` containing a checkbox in `BorderLayout.WEST` and a `JLabel` with icon and directory name in the `CENTER`.

Answer (score 3):

What about a [`JTree`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html)? I suggest you read the [How To Use Trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) tutorial as well.

Answer (score 3):

The JIDE commons package (open source) comes with a folder chooser. However, I am not sure wether it allows multiple selections with checkboxes. You'd have to take a look at it to check wether it does. I've used other components from the package and been happy with them, but I haven't used that particular component myself. You'll find it on [the JIDE website](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you can always make one yourself...

[image: File chooser combobox]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class JFileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JComboBox fileList;

    public JFileChooser() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel fileLabel = new JLabel("Select a file: ");
        fileList = new JComboBox(
            new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles() );
        JButton okbutton = new JButton("OK");
        JButton cancelbutton = new JButton("Cancel");
        okbutton.addActionListener(this);
        cancelbutton.addActionListener(this);
        add(fileLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(fileList, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel button = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.add(cancelbutton);
        button.add(okbutton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Cancel")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (command.equals("OK")) {
            Object result = fileList.getSelectedItem();
            String selectedFile = result.toString();
            System.out.println("SELECTED: "+ selectedFile);
            //do whatever you want with the file here
        }
    }
}

public class whatever extends JFrame {
    public whatever() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        add(chooser);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new whatever().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you have any questions or the code doesn't work, just ask. :)

Comment: *"If ..the code doesn't work.."*  It didn't.  Not as posted.  In the edit I posted source that does, defaulting to the user's home directory. *"If you have any questions ..just ask."* Yeah I do have one question.  Why did you post a solution based on a combo-box, when the original screen-shot depicted a tree?

Comment: @Andrew I'm kind of inexperienced with Java; haven't heard of `JTree`s until just now. And thank you for fixing my code (I know I should have been able to fix it myself :( ).

Comment: *"I should have been able to fix it myself"*  I was guessing you were, but did not have time to post a complete (compilable) solution.  Since I wanted to see it on-screen & had the time, I filled in the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at [CheckboxTree](http://zeus.pin.unifi.it/projectsSites/lablib-checkboxtree/):

> CheckboxTree is a Java Swing component that provides a Tree with checkboxes in every node. Checkboxes can toggle between two states (checked and unchecked). Disabling and greying checkboxes is also supported.

I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Some more details will make this answer better